# Can the iPhone be configured to read aloud (text) Messages as they come in?

Tags: ios, messages, automation, text-to-speech

Whether at my desk or in the car, it would be great to hear text messages read automatically when they arrive. Picking up the phone while driving is a bad idea and this feature could prevent a lot of car crashes.

Comment: This is a feature of CarPlay, all messages are read on request. Whilst driving without CarPlay, Driving Mode should be on, preventing any notification. If you have no Bluetooth to connect to in the car, this will not be automatic & you should enable manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using carplay or siri-compatible headphones, but yes.

**Settings > Notifications > Announce Notifications**

For text messages, siri will announce the message and then ask you if you want to have it read to you.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/have-siri-announce-calls-and-notifications-iph838fd6fd4/ios

Comment: Thanks so much! This is just what I wanted!